# Data does not exist

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I'm facing a very weird problem.

I've assigned a libname such as

```
libname TEST_LIB "/Info-One/...." /*have removed the exact location*/

/*The dataset TEST_DATA is visible in this output*/
proc datasets lib = TEST_LIB;
RUN;

/*This statement throws an error saying the file does not exist*/
DATA TEST_DATA_2;
  set TEST_LIB.TEST_DATA;
RUN;
```

I'm running this code in SAS Enterprise guide connected to the remote server.

I'm also able to navigate to the location from File explorer and drag it into Enterprise guide and then the dataset is visible. But even if I double click on the dataset from the defined library then it says that the dataset does not exist.

I've run out of ideas now and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this.

A couple of things that I've tried/checked

1. Case sensitivity is not an issue
2. The filename does not have spaces
3. I have permissions to the folder because I can work normally with another dataset that I created and placed in that folder
4. In fact if I copy the data to excel, upload the excel to SAS to create a SAS dataset and place it in the same location with a different name, I face the same issue!!

Would really appreciate any ideas that you guys may have, not just on why its happening, but also how to bypass it

Comment: Can you show the output from a proc contents? `proc contents data=test_lib.test_data; run`. I wonder if it's case sensitive...it's also possible the data set exists but is empty, how many records are showing with PROC DATASETS.

Comment: Is the remote server Windows, Unix or Mainframe ? After you drag and drop into EG library, does the table disappear when you refresh (right click menu) the library node ?

Comment: @Reeza Case sensitivity was the first thing I checked, still doesn't fix the issue. The dataset is not empty, when I drag it into EG I can see the rows. `PROC Contents` does not run because of the same error. `TEST_DATA does not exist`. And yes there are no spaces in the dataset name

Comment: @Richard I'm not entirely sure, but I think its Unix. Basically I can login to it with my credentials and server name `usehux491.orgame`. I can also access that folder using the windows file explorer because I think IT has set up a drive such that it is mapped to that location. But the location must be a Unix folder because I need to give write permissions to others before they can modify it using putty/filezilla. 
**No, the table does not disappear when I refresh the library node**

Comment: Here are 2 possibilities 1) data set filename case, Unix filenames for data sets (at the operating system level) should be lowercase.  If the actual file is mixed or uppercase the SAS session running on Unix wont like map properly (although you could try using a name-constant literal `"<actual-filename>"N` to reference the data set).   2) There is a file permission problem with the folder mount, allowing reading of directories but not files within.  What does Unix directory listing of the library path look like when you issue `ls -l`

Comment: When you try to open it check your log. Is there an error medsage? Try setting ‘options nofmterr;’ and see if that works. Can you post the output from Proc Datasets? Is it possible theres a space at end of file name. You can see dataset, so right click it select properties and check path.

Comment: @Richard Wow, thank you Ssssooooo much!!! This is the reason why I love Stack Overflow, we can find such experienced people out here.
I had checked for file permissions previously and Reeza I had checked spaces as well.
My dataset was in upper case and I don't completely understand why it happened but now that its in lowercase I'm not facing any issue.
Thank you so much for both of your help.
If you like you can post this as an answer so that it would be helpful for others, and if you have any suggestions I can edit the question so that it is useful for others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Transferred from comments and expanded

Here are 2 possibilities:

1. The filename of the data set may contain uppercase.  This is an unlikely but possible scenario:

   On Unix systems filenames are case sensitive.  A data set name in a SAS program will be mapped internally to a corresponding lowercase named data file (those `sas7bdat` files at the operating system level). If a copy process somehow creates a `.sas7bdat` data file on Unix whose name is mixed case or uppercase, the SAS session won't map to it. In such a scenario, the SAS file explorer might list a data set, but be unable to open it.  However, a direct file reference to the data set might work, such as 
    `set '~/project1/datasets/MyWeirdlyCasedDataset';`
2. There is a file permission problem with the folder mount, allowing reading of directory entries (the filenames) but not the file contents (the data sets) within.  Try opening a terminal session (putty or mobaxterm) and see what the detailed directory listing is for the data folder (`ls -l`)  You might have to also look at the access control lists (`lsacl`) and get network and IT admin involved.

Comment: Your first point is a little muddled. No matter what case you use in your SAS code the name of the physical file on Unix must be in all lowercase letters.

Comment: Hope the edit clarifies the scenario I was speculating

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is a dataset?
Put memtype=data in Proc Datasets as below

proc datasets lib = TEST_LIB memtype=data;
RUN;

Comment: Well it was a dataset, and the issue was what Richard pointed out in his first point.